# How do I set the duration of the output of a job in Elastic Transcoder using Django?

Tags: django, boto3, boto, amazon-elastic-transcoder, aws-elastictranscoder

I want to automate using Amazon's Elastic Transcoder to trim a video file in Django. The code so far is:

```
def trim_video(key, new_key, duration):

    pipeline_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXX'
    region = 'XXXXXXXX'

    transcoder_client = boto.elastictranscoder.connect_to_region(region)

    create_job_result=transcoder_client.create_job(**{
            'pipeline_id': pipeline_id,
            'input_name': {'Key': key},
            'output': {
                    'Key': new_key,
                    "PresetId": 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXX'
            }
        })
    print('Job has been created. The output key will be ' + new_key)
```

This code will cause the file to be transcoded but will not trim it. What do I add in order to trim the video?

Comment: One of these got it working: `'input_name': { 'Key': key, 'TimeSpan': {'Duration': str(1) }, 'Duration': str(1)}, 'output': { 'Key': new_key, "PresetId": 'XXXXXXXXXX-XXXX', 'TimeSpan': {'Duration': str(1) }, 'Duration': str(1)}`

Comment: Boto3 is better supported so I switched to it shortly after.